# Type-checking collections with elements with different traits

Tags: scala, types, typechecking, traits

Is there any way I can enforce a method returning something along the lines of (in regex notation):

```
(T with A) (T with A with B)+ (T with B)
```

If I return `Traversable[T]`, it drops the bound traits.  Likewise, I can't return `Traversable[T with A with B]`, because this would be inaccurate for the first and last elements.

I'm not sure how to get around this.  It introduces some implicit conditions into my program, and I feel like I'm abusing the type system by using `.asInstanceOf[]` casts.  Maybe I'm using the wrong kind of data structure?

Here's a sample of the code I'm writing, for an example of what I mean.  I'm looking to enforce the `route` method.  The `User` class extends type `T`, I've left out the code because there's a lot.

```
trait Producer extends User {
  def send(file: Data)
}

trait Consumer extends User {
  def receive(file: Data)
}

...

def route(sender: T with Producer, receiver: T with Consumer): Traversable[T]

def transfer(sender: T with Producer, receiver: T with Consumer, file: Data) {
  val path = route(sender, receiver)
  if (!path.isEmpty) {
    sender send file

    val nextHop = route(sender, receiver).tail.head

    nextHop.asInstanceOf[T with Consumer] receive file

    if (nextHop != receiver) {
      transfer(nextHop.asInstanceOf[T with Producer], receiver, file)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely avoid casts with `.asInstanceOf[]`.

Scala can easily return multiple values from a method using a Tuple, so why not return a 3-tuple of type `(T with A, Traversable[T with A with B], T with B)`?

Here's an example:

```
trait A
trait B
class T

def f(): (T with A, Traversable[T with A with B], T with B) = {
  (new T with A, List(new T with A with B), new T with B)
}

val (a, abs, b) = f()
```

Comment: Hmm...that's not a bad idea.  The reason why I was trying to cram them all together in one collection was because I wanted it to be more transparent whenever I called `route()`.  Thinking about it now though, I guess I could just flatten the tuple into a `Traversable[T]` if need be.